# Rust-SDL2 Transparent Background for Texture

Tags: rust, textures, sdl-2, alpha

Anybody have experience with https://rust-sdl2.github.io/rust-sdl2/sdl2/index.html? I can't seem to make a texture's background be transparent. My code looks something like the following:

```
let mut canvas = window.into_canvas().build().unwrap();
canvas.set_blend_mode(sdl2::render::BlendMode::Blend);

let texture_creator = canvas.texture_creator();
let mut texture = texture_creator.load_texture(std::path::Path::new(
    "path_to_png",
))?;
texture.set_blend_mode(sdl2::render::BlendMode::Blend);

canvas.copy_ex(&texture, None, None, 0., None, false, false)?;
canvas.present();
```

I've tried different permutations of blendmode without success. Help.

Edit: a reproducible example

```
extern crate sdl2;

use sdl2::event::Event;
use sdl2::image::LoadTexture;
use sdl2::keyboard::Keycode;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() -> Result<(), String> {
    let sdl_context = sdl2::init().unwrap();
    let video_subsystem = sdl_context.video().unwrap();

    let window = video_subsystem
        .window("rust-sdl2 demo", 800, 600)
        .position_centered()
        .build()
        .unwrap();

    let mut canvas = window.into_canvas().build().unwrap();
    canvas.default_pixel_format();
    canvas.set_blend_mode(sdl2::render::BlendMode::Blend);

    let texture_creator = canvas.texture_creator();
    texture_creator.default_pixel_format();
    let mut texture = texture_creator.load_texture(std::path::Path::new(
        "someimage.png",
    ))?;
    texture.set_blend_mode(sdl2::render::BlendMode::None);

    let mut event_pump = sdl_context.event_pump().unwrap();
    'running: loop {
        for event in event_pump.poll_iter() {
            match event {
                Event::KeyDown {
                    keycode: Some(Keycode::Escape),
                    ..
                } => break 'running,
                _ => {}
            }
        }
        canvas.clear();
        canvas.copy_ex(&texture, None, None, 0., None, false, false)?;
        canvas.present();
        std::thread::sleep(Duration::new(0, 1_000_000_000u32 / 60));
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Does your PNG file have an alpha channel?

Comment: Yes. And to be certain it wasn't an image issue, I used several Google images

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Added an edit to my original post

Comment: I just tried your example, but with `texture.set_blend_mode(BlendMode::Blend);` and it works for me. Maybe you are on a [MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46978001/865874)?

Comment: I am on a linux machine